# MySQL: How to still return a value from a WHERE NOT EXISTS clause

Tags: mysql, sql

In my query, I am attempting to remove all objects that are close to each other for a map application using the following query in a nodeJS server:

```
var diff = 1.7;

SELECT m1.marker_id, m1.longitude, m1.latitude
        FROM Marker m1
        WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
            /* remove all but one */
            SELECT * FROM Marker m2
            WHERE m1.marker_id != m2. marker_id
            AND m1.latitude <= m2.latitude + ${diff}
            AND m1.latitude >= m2.latitude - ${diff}
            AND m1.longitude <= m2.longitude + ${diff}
            AND m1.longitude >= m2.longitude - ${diff}
            )
```

This query removes all rows that return `WHERE NOT EXISTS` true as intended.

However, I would still like to return one of the rows that get removed so there is still a marker at that location.

Is there a way to do this?

Marker table:

```
     'Marker', 
    'CREATE TABLE `Marker` (
    `marker_id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
     `latitude` decimal(20,15) NOT NULL, 
     `longitude` decimal(20,15) NOT NULL,  
    PRIMARY KEY (`marker_id`),  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`marker_id`)\n) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=45 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'
```

Comment: Please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE Marker;`, copy the result and your sample data [into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72945421/edit). Provide the value of `${diff}` as well, it might be useful.

Comment: diff is an input so it is different every time and Marker only has the three columns that are listed

Comment: That's understandable but you need to create a scenario whereby from a sample data with a specific `diff` value should return what result according to your condition. As for the table `Marker`, if you're referring to this `m1.marker_id, m1.longitude, m1.latitude` as three rows, it's actually _three columns_ and the reason I asked for `SHOW CREATE TABLE Marker;` is to know your table information, especially each column datatype.

Comment: I edited my question with the table and a ${diff} value

Comment: The create table syntax is invalid.. you don't have `marker_id` column and you're attempting to make `geoPost_id` as `AUTO_INCREMENT` while defining the non-existing `marker_id` column as `PRIMARY KEY`, you also attempting to create a `UNIQUE KEY` on it. It's fine if you want to post a fake sample data, we wouldn't want any real data to begin with but at least give the real table structure, I mean, what sensitive information does a table structure hold anyway?

Comment: that was a typo it is marker_id

Comment: Now, take a look at this fiddle. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=beb450263db68571a21f62847c68901d and tell us from that set of sample data, what is the result you're looking for?